# How to set the default route once Authenticated?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I want two controllers to sit at the same route, but one to handle when there is no one logged in, and one to handle when someone is authenticated.

Is there a way to set this up?

Comment: custom auth schemes run before every request (even if you don't use `[Authorize]`). you should be able to use this to your advantage

Answer (score 1):

Just an example:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Logged",
        "SomeUrl",
        new {controller = "Default", action = "Index"},
        new {controller = new MustBeLoggedIn()}
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "NotLogged",
        "SomeUrl",
        new { controller = "Auth", action = "Index" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});

public class MustBeLoggedIn : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContext httpContext, IRouter route, string routeKey, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        return httpContext.User?.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false;
    }
}
```

How to set user authenticated state is up to your choice.